# Fatal signal 11 error while writing native code in Android

Tags: java, android

I am doing an Android app with native code.
I have the typical error "fatal signal", wich usually means that in my native code there is a problem. But this time I dind't find the error.

This is the Logcat:

```
06-04 09:48:19.115: D/dalvikvm(27203): GC_CONCURRENT freed 460K, 4% free 17100K/17700K, paused 0ms+2ms, total 14ms
06-04 09:48:19.165: A/libc(27328): Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0x00000000 (code=1), thread 27344 (Binder_3)
06-04 09:48:19.215: A/libc(27328): Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0x00000000 (code=1), thread 27369 (bucle)
06-04 09:48:19.265: I/DEBUG(26629): *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
06-04 09:48:19.265: I/DEBUG(26629): Build fingerprint: 'google/hammerhead/hammerhead:4.4.2/KOT49H/937116:user/release-keys'
06-04 09:48:19.265: I/DEBUG(26629): Revision: '11'
06-04 09:48:19.265: I/DEBUG(26629): pid: 27328, tid: 27344, name: Binder_3  >>> org.gradiant.sistole.locservice <<<
06-04 09:48:19.265: I/DEBUG(26629): signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 00000000
06-04 09:48:19.345: I/DEBUG(26629):     r0 00000000  r1 c0186201  r2 00000000  r3 00000000
06-04 09:48:19.345: I/DEBUG(26629):     r4 74ec7740  r5 74ec7710  r6 74ec7770  r7 00000001
06-04 09:48:19.345: I/DEBUG(26629):     r8 00000001  r9 752df000  sl 74da7bd4  fp 4016f2ec
06-04 09:48:19.345: I/DEBUG(26629):     ip 00000001  sp 753dccf0  lr 00000000  pc 00000000  cpsr 000a0010
06-04 09:48:19.345: I/DEBUG(26629):     d0  752de00000000000  d1  0000000800000000
06-04 09:48:19.345: I/DEBUG(26629):     d2  0074006e00610000  d3  0073006900730000
06-04 09:48:19.345: I/DEBUG(26629):     d4  0065006c006f0074  d5  0063006f006c002e
06-04 09:48:19.345: I/DEBUG(26629):     d6  0076007200650073  d7  002e006500630069
06-04 09:48:19.345: I/DEBUG(26629):     d8  0000000000000000  d9  0000000000000000
06-04 09:48:19.345: I/DEBUG(26629):     d10 0000000000000000  d11 0000000000000000
06-04 09:48:19.345: I/DEBUG(26629):     d12 0000000000000000  d13 0000000000000000
06-04 09:48:19.345: I/DEBUG(26629):     d14 0000000000000000  d15 0000000000000000
06-04 09:48:19.345: I/DEBUG(26629):     d16 4000000000000000  d17 00000006ffffffff
06-04 09:48:19.345: I/DEBUG(26629):     d18 0000000000000000  d19 0000000000000000
06-04 09:48:19.345: I/DEBUG(26629):     d20 0000000000000000  d21 0000004400000044
06-04 09:48:19.345: I/DEBUG(26629):     d22 0000000000000000  d23 0000000000000000
06-04 09:48:19.345: I/DEBUG(26629):     d24 0000000000000000  d25 0002a7600002a760
06-04 09:48:19.345: I/DEBUG(26629):     d26 0707070703030303  d27 0300000004000000
06-04 09:48:19.345: I/DEBUG(26629):     d28 0800000009000000  d29 0001000000010000
06-04 09:48:19.345: I/DEBUG(26629):     d30 010b400001088000  d31 01108000010e0000
06-04 09:48:19.345: I/DEBUG(26629):     scr 80000010
06-04 09:48:19.345: I/DEBUG(26629): backtrace:
06-04 09:48:19.345: I/DEBUG(26629):     #00  pc 00000000  <unknown>
06-04 09:48:19.345: I/DEBUG(26629): stack:
06-04 09:48:19.345: I/DEBUG(26629):          753dccb0  00000000  
06-04 09:48:19.345: I/DEBUG(26629):          753dccb4  00000000  
06-04 09:48:19.345: I/DEBUG(26629):          753dccb8  00000000  
06-04 09:48:19.345: I/DEBUG(26629):          753dccbc  00000000  
06-04 09:48:19.345: I/DEBUG(26629):          753dccc0  00000000  
06-04 09:48:19.345: I/DEBUG(26629):          753dccc4  00000000  
06-04 09:48:19.345: I/DEBUG(26629):          753dccc8  00000000  
06-04 09:48:19.345: I/DEBUG(26629):          753dcccc  00000000  
06-04 09:48:19.345: I/DEBUG(26629):          753dccd0  00000000  
06-04 09:48:19.345: I/DEBUG(26629):          753dccd4  00000000  
06-04 09:48:19.345: I/DEBUG(26629):          753dccd8  00000000  
06-04 09:48:19.345: I/DEBUG(26629):          753dccdc  00000000  
06-04 09:48:19.345: I/DEBUG(26629):          753dcce0  00000000  
06-04 09:48:19.345: I/DEBUG(26629):          753dcce4  00000000  
06-04 09:48:19.345: I/DEBUG(26629):          753dcce8  00000000  
06-04 09:48:19.345: I/DEBUG(26629):          753dccec  00000000  
06-04 09:48:19.345: I/DEBUG(26629):     #00  753dccf0  00000008  
06-04 09:48:19.345: I/DEBUG(26629):          753dccf4  00000008  
06-04 09:48:19.345: I/DEBUG(26629):          753dccf8  753e3a70  [anon:libc_malloc]
06-04 09:48:19.345: I/DEBUG(26629):          753dccfc  00000100  
06-04 09:48:19.345: I/DEBUG(26629):          753dcd00  00000030  
06-04 09:48:19.345: I/DEBUG(26629):          753dcd04  753e3968  [anon:libc_malloc]
06-04 09:48:19.345: I/DEBUG(26629):          753dcd08  00000000  
06-04 09:48:19.345: I/DEBUG(26629):          753dcd0c  00000000  
06-04 09:48:19.345: I/DEBUG(26629):          753dcd10  00000000  
06-04 09:48:19.345: I/DEBUG(26629):          753dcd14  00000000  
06-04 09:48:19.345: I/DEBUG(26629):          753dcd18  00000000  
06-04 09:48:19.345: I/DEBUG(26629):          753dcd1c  00000000  
06-04 09:48:19.345: I/DEBUG(26629):          753dcd20  00000000  
06-04 09:48:19.345: I/DEBUG(26629):          753dcd24  00000000  
06-04 09:48:19.345: I/DEBUG(26629):          753dcd28  00000000  
06-04 09:48:19.345: I/DEBUG(26629):          753dcd2c  00000000  
06-04 09:48:19.345: I/DEBUG(26629): memory near r4:
06-04 09:48:19.345: I/DEBUG(26629):     74ec7720 00000000 00000007 00000004 401e66c0  
06-04 09:48:19.345: I/DEBUG(26629):     74ec7730 752deef8 00000000 00000007 00000004  
06-04 09:48:19.345: I/DEBUG(26629):     74ec7740 00000000 753e3968 00000008 00000100  
06-04 09:48:19.345: I/DEBUG(26629):     74ec7750 00000008 00000000 00000000 00000000  
06-04 09:48:19.345: I/DEBUG(26629):     74ec7760 00000000 00010001 00000000 00000000  
06-04 09:48:19.345: I/DEBUG(26629):     74ec7770 00000000 753e3a70 00000008 00000100  
06-04 09:48:19.345: I/DEBUG(26629):     74ec7780 00000008 00000000 00000000 00000000  
06-04 09:48:19.345: I/DEBUG(26629):     74ec7790 00000000 00010001 00000000 00000000  
06-04 09:48:19.345: I/DEBUG(26629):     74ec77a0 00000006 00006ac0 00002792 00000000  
06-04 09:48:19.345: I/DEBUG(26629):     74ec77b0 00000010 00000013 00020182 02020200  
06-04 09:48:19.345: I/DEBUG(26629):     74ec77c0 00000010 00000013 00030184 01040004  
06-04 09:48:19.345: I/DEBUG(26629):     74ec77d0 00000001 00000013 00020182 04060402  
06-04 09:48:19.345: I/DEBUG(26629):     74ec77e0 00000010 00000013 00020182 02050202  
06-04 09:48:19.345: I/DEBUG(26629):     74ec77f0 00000000 0000005b 74ec81d8 42400000  
06-04 09:48:19.345: I/DEBUG(26629):     74ec7800 3f800000 00000000 00000000 00000000  
06-04 09:48:19.345: I/DEBUG(26629):     74ec7810 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  
06-04 09:48:19.345: I/DEBUG(26629): memory near r5:
06-04 09:48:19.345: I/DEBUG(26629):     74ec76f0 d1d1d1d1 d1d1d1d1 d1d1d1d1 d1d1d1d1  
06-04 09:48:19.345: I/DEBUG(26629):     74ec7700 d1d1d1d1 d1d1d1d1 00000000 000000ab  
06-04 09:48:19.345: I/DEBUG(26629):     74ec7710 71450768 00006ad0 401e6698 732cf0e8  
06-04 09:48:19.345: I/DEBUG(26629):     74ec7720 00000000 00000007 00000004 401e66c0  
06-04 09:48:19.345: I/DEBUG(26629):     74ec7730 752deef8 00000000 00000007 00000004  
06-04 09:48:19.345: I/DEBUG(26629):     74ec7740 00000000 753e3968 00000008 00000100  
06-04 09:48:19.345: I/DEBUG(26629):     74ec7750 00000008 00000000 00000000 00000000  
06-04 09:48:19.345: I/DEBUG(26629):     74ec7760 00000000 00010001 00000000 00000000  
06-04 09:48:19.345: I/DEBUG(26629):     74ec7770 00000000 753e3a70 00000008 00000100  
06-04 09:48:19.345: I/DEBUG(26629):     74ec7780 00000008 00000000 00000000 00000000  
06-04 09:48:19.345: I/DEBUG(26629):     74ec7790 00000000 00010001 00000000 00000000  
06-04 09:48:19.345: I/DEBUG(26629):     74ec77a0 00000006 00006ac0 00002792 00000000  
06-04 09:48:19.345: I/DEBUG(26629):     74ec77b0 00000010 00000013 00020182 02020200  
06-04 09:48:19.345: I/DEBUG(26629):     74ec77c0 00000010 00000013 00030184 01040004  
06-04 09:48:19.345: I/DEBUG(26629):     74ec77d0 00000001 00000013 00020182 04060402  
06-04 09:48:19.345: I/DEBUG(26629):     74ec77e0 00000010 00000013 00020182 02050202  
06-04 09:48:19.345: I/DEBUG(26629): memory near r6:
06-04 09:48:19.345: I/DEBUG(26629):     74ec7750 00000008 00000000 00000000 00000000  
06-04 09:48:19.345: I/DEBUG(26629):     74ec7760 00000000 00010001 00000000 00000000  
06-04 09:48:19.345: I/DEBUG(26629):     74ec7770 00000000 753e3a70 00000008 00000100  
06-04 09:48:19.345: I/DEBUG(26629):     74ec7780 00000008 00000000 00000000 00000000  
06-04 09:48:19.345: I/DEBUG(26629):     74ec7790 00000000 00010001 00000000 00000000  
06-04 09:48:19.345: I/DEBUG(26629):     74ec77a0 00000006 00006ac0 00002792 00000000  
06-04 09:48:19.345: I/DEBUG(26629):     74ec77b0 00000010 00000013 00020182 02020200  
06-04 09:48:19.345: I/DEBUG(26629):     74ec77c0 00000010 00000013 00030184 01040004  
06-04 09:48:19.345: I/DEBUG(26629):     74ec77d0 00000001 00000013 00020182 04060402  
06-04 09:48:19.345: I/DEBUG(26629):     74ec77e0 00000010 00000013 00020182 02050202  
06-04 09:48:19.345: I/DEBUG(26629):     74ec77f0 00000000 0000005b 74ec81d8 42400000  
06-04 09:48:19.345: I/DEBUG(26629):     74ec7800 3f800000 00000000 00000000 00000000  
06-04 09:48:19.345: I/DEBUG(26629):     74ec7810 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  
06-04 09:48:19.345: I/DEBUG(26629):     74ec7820 75511410 00000000 00000000 ff000000  
06-04 09:48:19.345: I/DEBUG(26629):     74ec7830 00000000 40800000 0b000501 72e90568  
06-04 09:48:19.345: I/DEBUG(26629):     74ec7840 00000001 00000001 00000010 00000013  
06-04 09:48:19.345: I/DEBUG(26629): memory near r9:
06-04 09:48:19.345: I/DEBUG(26629):     752defe0 752cb000 00014000 7504ffe0 00000001  
06-04 09:48:19.345: I/DEBUG(26629):     752deff0 00000000 00000007 00000007 00000007  
06-04 09:48:19.345: I/DEBUG(26629):     752df000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  
06-04 09:48:19.345: I/DEBUG(26629):     752df010 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  
06-04 09:48:19.345: I/DEBUG(26629):     752df020 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  
06-04 09:48:19.345: I/DEBUG(26629):     752df030 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  
06-04 09:48:19.345: I/DEBUG(26629):     752df040 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  
06-04 09:48:19.345: I/DEBUG(26629):     752df050 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  
06-04 09:48:19.345: I/DEBUG(26629):     752df060 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  
06-04 09:48:19.345: I/DEBUG(26629):     752df070 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  
06-04 09:48:19.345: I/DEBUG(26629):     752df080 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  
06-04 09:48:19.345: I/DEBUG(26629):     752df090 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  
06-04 09:48:19.345: I/DEBUG(26629):     752df0a0 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  
06-04 09:48:19.345: I/DEBUG(26629):     752df0b0 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  
06-04 09:48:19.345: I/DEBUG(26629):     752df0c0 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  
06-04 09:48:19.345: I/DEBUG(26629):     752df0d0 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  
06-04 09:48:19.345: I/DEBUG(26629): memory near sl:
06-04 09:48:19.345: I/DEBUG(26629):     74da7bb4 401de055 74dae0c0 00007206 00000000  
06-04 09:48:19.345: I/DEBUG(26629):     74da7bc4 401da885 74dae0f0 74da7bec 74dae244  
06-04 09:48:19.345: I/DEBUG(26629):     74da7bd4 401dd5f5 74da7cac 40171384 74da7c4c  
06-04 09:48:19.345: I/DEBUG(26629):     74da7be4 401da4c5 401e8df0 74da7cac 74da7c0c  
06-04 09:48:19.345: I/DEBUG(26629):     74da7bf4 74da7cac 74da7c24 401d6895 401e90e0  
06-04 09:48:19.345: I/DEBUG(26629):     74da7c04 401df2ab 752ddff8 00000000 40171384  
06-04 09:48:19.345: I/DEBUG(26629):     74da7c14 752de000 74bab090 74da7c7c 0000000f  
06-04 09:48:19.345: I/DEBUG(26629):     74da7c24 74dae0f0 74bab028 401da237 74bab090  
06-04 09:48:19.345: I/DEBUG(26629):     74da7c34 74da7c7c 401da21d 401dd341 00000000  
06-04 09:48:19.345: I/DEBUG(26629):     74da7c44 74dae090 00000001 74da7c7c 00000010  
06-04 09:48:19.345: I/DEBUG(26629):     74da7c54 401dd3bd 74dae090 401da779 00000010  
06-04 09:48:19.345: I/DEBUG(26629):     74da7c64 401da21d 74dae090 415b158b 7504ef60  
06-04 09:48:19.345: I/DEBUG(26629):     74da7c74 7504ef78 7504ee30 00000000 74bab028  
06-04 09:48:19.345: I/DEBUG(26629):     74da7c84 00000068 00000068 00000068 74bab090  
06-04 09:48:19.345: I/DEBUG(26629):     74da7c94 00000000 00000000 00000000 00010001  
06-04 09:48:19.345: I/DEBUG(26629):     74da7ca4 401da21d 74dae090 00000000 752de000  
06-04 09:48:19.345: I/DEBUG(26629): memory near fp:
06-04 09:48:19.345: I/DEBUG(26629):     4016f2cc 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  
06-04 09:48:19.345: I/DEBUG(26629):     4016f2dc 00000000 00000000 ffffffff 00000000  
06-04 09:48:19.345: I/DEBUG(26629):     4016f2ec 00000000 00000001 00ffffff 00000000  
06-04 09:48:19.345: I/DEBUG(26629):     4016f2fc 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  
06-04 09:48:19.345: I/DEBUG(26629):     4016f30c 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  
06-04 09:48:19.345: I/DEBUG(26629):     4016f31c 00000000 00000000 40135a4d 40135a49  
06-04 09:48:19.345: I/DEBUG(26629):     4016f32c 401363fb 40136535 00000000 00000000  
06-04 09:48:19.345: I/DEBUG(26629):     4016f33c 00000000 00000000 415a4145 401365c9  
06-04 09:48:19.345: I/DEBUG(26629):     4016f34c 4054bd55 00000000 00000000 00000000  
06-04 09:48:19.345: I/DEBUG(26629):     4016f35c 401aade1 401da3ed 750162d5 00000000  
06-04 09:48:19.345: I/DEBUG(26629):     4016f36c 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  
06-04 09:48:19.345: I/DEBUG(26629):     4016f37c 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  
06-04 09:48:19.345: I/DEBUG(26629):     4016f38c 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  
06-04 09:48:19.345: I/DEBUG(26629):     4016f39c 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  
06-04 09:48:19.345: I/DEBUG(26629):     4016f3ac 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  
06-04 09:48:19.345: I/DEBUG(26629):     4016f3bc 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  
06-04 09:48:19.345: I/DEBUG(26629): memory near sp:
06-04 09:48:19.345: I/DEBUG(26629):     753dccd0 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  
06-04 09:48:19.345: I/DEBUG(26629):     753dcce0 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  
06-04 09:48:19.345: I/DEBUG(26629):     753dccf0 00000008 00000008 753e3a70 00000100  
06-04 09:48:19.345: I/DEBUG(26629):     753dcd00 00000030 753e3968 00000000 00000000  
06-04 09:48:19.345: I/DEBUG(26629):     753dcd10 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  
06-04 09:48:19.345: I/DEBUG(26629):     753dcd20 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  
06-04 09:48:19.345: I/DEBUG(26629):     753dcd30 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  
06-04 09:48:19.345: I/DEBUG(26629):     753dcd40 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  
06-04 09:48:19.345: I/DEBUG(26629):     753dcd50 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  
06-04 09:48:19.345: I/DEBUG(26629):     753dcd60 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  
06-04 09:48:19.345: I/DEBUG(26629):     753dcd70 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  
06-04 09:48:19.345: I/DEBUG(26629):     753dcd80 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  
06-04 09:48:19.345: I/DEBUG(26629):     753dcd90 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  
06-04 09:48:19.345: I/DEBUG(26629):     753dcda0 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  
06-04 09:48:19.345: I/DEBUG(26629):     753dcdb0 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  
06-04 09:48:19.345: I/DEBUG(26629):     753dcdc0 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  
06-04 09:48:19.345: I/DEBUG(26629): code around pc:
06-04 09:48:19.345: I/DEBUG(26629):     00000000 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
06-04 09:48:19.345: I/DEBUG(26629):     00000010 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
06-04 09:48:19.345: I/DEBUG(26629):     00000020 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
06-04 09:48:19.345: I/DEBUG(26629):     00000030 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
06-04 09:48:19.345: I/DEBUG(26629):     00000040 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
06-04 09:48:19.345: I/DEBUG(26629):     00000050 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
06-04 09:48:19.345: I/DEBUG(26629):     00000060 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
06-04 09:48:19.345: I/DEBUG(26629):     00000070 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
06-04 09:48:19.345: I/DEBUG(26629):     00000080 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
06-04 09:48:19.345: I/DEBUG(26629):     00000090 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
06-04 09:48:19.345: I/DEBUG(26629):     000000a0 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
06-04 09:48:19.345: I/DEBUG(26629):     000000b0 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
06-04 09:48:19.345: I/DEBUG(26629):     000000c0 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
06-04 09:48:19.345: I/DEBUG(26629):     000000d0 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
06-04 09:48:19.345: I/DEBUG(26629):     000000e0 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
06-04 09:48:19.345: I/DEBUG(26629):     000000f0 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
06-04 09:48:19.425: I/DEBUG(26629): ptrace detach from 27344 failed: No such process
06-04 09:48:19.425: I/DEBUG(26629): debuggerd committing suicide to free the zombie!
06-04 09:48:19.425: I/DEBUG(27386): debuggerd: Dec  4 2013 23:14:10
```

When I not call the native function, the error does not occur, so I supose the native code causes the error. The conflictive code is:

```
((ParametersUWB*) retorno)->pos_nodos[6] = i3[4];
((ParametersUWB*) retorno)->pos_nodos[7] = i3[5];
((ParametersUWB*) retorno)->pos_nodos[8] = i3[6];

double dist[6];
dist[0] = i3[7];
dist[1] = i1[0];
dist[2] = i2[0];
dist[3] = i3[0];
dist[4] = i3[2];
dist[5] = 0;

double erro[6];
erro[0] = i3[8];
erro[1] = i1[1];
erro[2] = i2[1];
erro[3] = i3[1];
erro[4] = i3[3];
erro[5] = 0.001;

ret_cop = ((ParametersUWB*) retorno)->cop.process(((ParametersUWB*) retorno)->pos_nodos, dist, erro);

((ParametersUWB*) retorno)->pos_est[0] = ret_cop(0, 0);
((ParametersUWB*) retorno)->pos_est[1] = ret_cop(1, 0);
```

What is the problem and how do I fix it?

Comment: Signal 11 usually means that you have a C/C++ memory-management bug.

Answer (score 0):

It is very likely that you use a deleted or uninitialized reference. You should add logs to the lines to see which line it breaks. Then you can start to investigate where you made a mistake about references.

Comment: I tried with logs but not appears, so seems that error is caused in java´s size because never appears the logs messages when app crashes, in fact not go into in native code